# Force admin to show app regardless of permissions

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-admin

The project I am working on has divorced itself from the django permission model, and uses a homegrown permission system.

This is a problem with the django admin. All of you our models.py hase code similer this:

```
def is_admin(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name__contains="APP Admin").exists()

def is_publisher(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name="101 - APP Publisher").exists()

def is_app_user(user):
    return is_admin(user) or is_publisher(user) or user.is_superuser

#admin.site.disable_action('delete_selected')

class DefaultPermitMixin(object):
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return is_app_user(request.user)

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return request.user.is_superuser

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return request.user.is_superuser
```

All of the ModelAdmins derive from DefaultPermitMixin and most of them have a `get_readonly_fields` function to implement field or object level permissions.

The problem is that django-admin is using Permissions to decide whether to show an app at all. If I give a user just one permission form our app, the everything works like it should. If a user has no Permissions for an app, the app is hidden, even if `has_*_permission` would return true.

It there a way to override this behavior and force the admin to show my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a custom auth backend and override the `has_module_perms` method:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: Yeah, that looks like the only reasonable way to do it. I was hoping for something on AdminSite. Oh well.